# Calling Postgres function using QueryDSL

Tags: postgresql, querydsl

I have a package with similarity functions installed on my Postgres DB. I was calling them using pure SQL on a JDBC, and it was working as expected.

Now I'm trying to refactor my code to use QueryDSL. The first step of the similarity function is set a limit, between 0 and 1, so that only results above that given threshold are returned. I'm trying this way:

`NumberExpression<Float> sim = Expressions.numberTemplate(Float.class, "set_limit({0})", "0.2");
query.singleResult(sim);`

I get the following error:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No joins given`

I know I haven't passed an EntityPath. If I try and use any EntityPath, I get the error:

```
`[[IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'set_limit' {originalText=set_limit}
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       \-[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=1, expectedType=null}
]]`
```

After that, I'd call another DB function, but I guess the solution would be the same.

Is this possible with QueryDSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set_limit` isn't valid JPQL, that's why Hibernate throws an exception. Querydsl JPA maps internally to JPQL, and Querydsl SQL to SQL.

If you need SQL expressivity, like in this case, you will need to use Querydsl SQL instead.